# How to continue writing an equation in the next line in the IEEE journal papers format?

Tags: equations, amsmath, two-column, multicolumn, ieeetran

I want to write this equation in multi-line, but it's not possible in the IEEE format. please help:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{equation}
\label{longEq}
X(t + 1) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
        {{X_\text{rand}}(t) - {r_1}\left| {{X_\text{rand}}(t) - 2{r_2}X(t)} \right|{\rm{                    }}q \le 0.5}\\
        {\left( {{X_\text{prey}}(t) - {X_m}(t)} \right) - {r_3}\left( {LB + {r_4}\left( {UB - LB} \right)} \right){\rm{   }}q > 0.5}
\end{array}} \right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide a Minimal Working Example, so that people can copy-paste your code to test and modify it. Thanks.

Comment: `equation` does not allow line breaks, use `align` or `gather` from `amsmath`.

Comment: Unrelated: never use syntax like `X_\text{rand}`: (1) it is pure luck that it works and there is no guarantee that it will keep working, remember braces `X_{\text{rand}}`. (2) the use of `\text` is wrong, this is not what `\text` is for (sadly a **very** common mistake). Use `\mathrm` or `\textrm` instead. Why not `\text`? Try `\itshape $X_{\text{rand}}$` that is probably not what you wanted, thus `\text` is not the proper construction to use.,

Comment: Note without a proper minimal example, you question will just be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make `{array}` work, but it looks like you're trying for a piece-wise definition, which `{cases}` from `amsmath` is built for.  Some other notes:

- As noted, `\text` is for when you want the argument to match the surrounding text.  In this case, you want the argument to be the same regardless of whether the surrounding text is emphasized or not.  Consequently, you want to use `\mathrm` (or maybe `\mathit`).
- `{...}` makes a group, and should only be used when you need a group.  It's (almost) mandatory for a complicated subscript like `\mathrm{}`, `\mathit{}`, or `\text{}`; optional for a one character subscript; and should not be used if you don't need the grouping (for example, `{r_1}`).
- If you don't need the sizing, then you should remove the `$\left...\right$`, since they just make your tex more complicated.  (Some people prefer to always manually size instead of ever using the automatic sizing.)
- `|` should become `\lvert...\rvert`, since they have the correct horizontal spacing.
- The purpose of \label is to not use numbers.  Otherwise, if you rearrange your source, you have to renumber everything.  Instead, give a meaningful name to your equation, so that when you're at a separate part of your document, you can `\ref` the equation without needing to look back at what number you used.
- Spaces are generally ignored in math mode, so `{(lots of spaces)}` wasn't going to work.  There are spacing commands, but they should be used sparingly.
- `\rm` should no longer be used in LaTeX.  It's replacement should be used even more sparingly.  (It also doesn't take an argument; you would want `{\replacement stuff}`.)
- It is helpful if you include the documentclass and relevant packages so that we can copy and paste what you're doing and immediately see the output.

The result:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:nextX}
X(t + 1) = \begin{cases}
    X_{\mathrm{rand}}(t) - r_1\lvert X_{\mathrm{rand}}(t) - 2r_2X(t) \rvert
    & q \le 0.5\\
    ( X_{\mathrm{prey}}(t) - X_m(t) ) - r_3( LB+r_4(UB - LB)) & q > 0.5
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Edit:

The two column IEEEtran class doesn't give you much room to work with.  One possibility is to use `multlined` from `mathtools` (and changed `cases` to `dcases`), ending up with:

```tex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:nextX}
X(t + 1) = \begin{dcases}
    \begin{multlined}
        X_{\mathrm{rand}}(t) - {} \\ % - {} to get correct spacing
        r_1\lvert X_{\mathrm{rand}}(t) - 2r_2X(t) \rvert
    \end{multlined}
    & q \le 0.5\\
    \begin{multlined}
        X_{\mathrm{prey}}(t) - X_m(t) - {} \\ % - {} to get correct spacing
        r_3( LB+r_4(UB - LB))
    \end{multlined}
    & q > 0.5
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This solution doesn't fit into `ieeetran` documentclass ...

Comment: It's a fairly long equation to fit into `IEEEtran`, but it can be done with mathtools, dcases, and multlined (although it's not very pretty).  Or we could pass `onecolumn` as a class option.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. The points you mentioned are priceless to me and all of them are the points that can help me a lot in the way of writing my papers in Latex.
I replaced your codes instead of mine, because I am writing a two-column material, some part of it will be written in the front column that is unpleasant. Please help me to solve it.
Unfortunately, I am new to Latex and I write my codes by searching on the internet, but I added some of the packages. Thank you again

Comment: @SadeghE IEEEtran doesn't give you much room to work with, but it can be done.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added the new library and the problem has been solved. May you please tell me that what should I do with 1 long equation with convenient alignment?

Comment: If it's a completely different equation, it would probably be better as a new question.  If it's related to this equation, I'm not quite understanding what you're asking.